# Make navigation change to `position: fixed` when scrolled X amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the navigation to change to `position: fixed` right underneath the black header. I'm pretty sure the JavaScript needs some tweaking but I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgnkxemd/2/

HTML

```
<div>
    <header></header>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <ul id="site-navigation">
        <li>nav 1</li>
        <li>nav 2</li>
        <li>nav 3</li>
        <li>nav 4</li>
    </ul>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 100px
}
header {
    background: #000;
    height: 60px;    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#site-navigation {
    background: yellow;
}
#site-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#site-navigation.fix-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
// Fixed nav
var nav = $("#site-navigation");

nav.on("scroll", function(e) {

  if (this.scrollTop > 60) {
    nav.addClass("fix-nav");
  } else {
    nav.removeClass("fix-nav");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but there are a couple problems.

Firstly, you don't want to bind the scroll event to the nav, because the nav isn't scrolling; the window is. So you need to bind the scroll event to the window. Then you need to check the scroll position of the window using `$(window).scrollTop()` ( or `$(this).scrollTop()` inside the scroll event )

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 60 ) {
    nav.addClass("fix-nav");
  } else {
    nav.removeClass("fix-nav");
  }
});
```

Making these changes results in this: http://jsfiddle.net/kgnkxemd/3/

Comment: What does the `60` in the JS represent? Is that the total pixel amount that the window has to scroll? If so, why does it jump [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnkxemd/7/)? However, when I change it to `45`, it works better like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnkxemd/6/).

Comment: Yeah, 60 means 60 pixels from the top of the screen. The reason it works better with 45 is because you want it to become fixed when it hits the black bar. So the number needs to be the distance between the bottom of the black bar and the top of the yellow nav. Which, if you measure it, is 40px.

Comment: Just figured that out myself right as you posted it :) Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

`scrolltop()` is a function not a property. Update your script like below.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var nav = $("#site-navigation");
  $(document).on("scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 60) {
      nav.addClass("fix-nav");
     } else {
     nav.removeClass("fix-nav");
    }     
  });    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnkxemd/5/)